# Gradle- How to override creating a lib directory in EAR

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I Want to reflect the jars to be included in base dir instead of creating a lib directory in the EAR, is there any workaround to overcome the lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need set the libDirName parameter of the ear plugin to change the location of the libraries in the ear.

**See example:**

```
apply plugin: 'ear'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    earlib group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-math3', version: '3.6.1'
}

ear {
    libDirName '.'
}
```